# How to count elements in an array withtin a given increasing interval?

Tags: python

I have an array of time values. I want to know how many values are in each 0.05 seconds window.

For example, some values of my array are: `-1.9493, -1.9433, -1.911 , -1.8977, -1.8671,..`

In the first interval of 0.050 seconds (from -1.9493 to -1.893) I´m expecting to have 3 elements

I already create another array with the 0.050 seconds steps.

```
    a=max(array)
    b=min(array)
    ventanalinea1=np.arange(b,a,0.05)
    v1=np.array(ventanalinea1)
```

In other words, I would like to compare my original array with this one.

I would like to know if there is a way to ask python to evaluate my array within a given dynamic range.

Comment: You can use `np.where()` for this or any other logical comparison. *Q for you:* which is your original array?

Answer (score 1):

One of the variants:

```
import numpy as np

# original array
a = [-1.9493, -1.9433, -1.911 , -1.8977, -1.8671]

step = 0.05
bounds = np.arange(min(a), max(a) + step, step)

result = [
    list(filter(lambda x: b[i] <= x <= b[i+1], a))
    for i in range(len(b)-1)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a cool python library [`python-intervals`](https://pypi.org/project/python-intervals/) that simplify your problem a lot:

Install it with `pip install python-intervals` and try the code below.

```
import intervals as I  

# This is a recursive function
def counter(timevalues, w=0.050):
    if not timevalues:
        return "" # stops recursion when timevalues is empty
    # Make an interval object that provides convenient interval operations like 'contains'
    window = I.closed(
        timevalues[0], timevalues[0] + w)
    interval = list(
        filter(window.contains, timevalues))
    count = len(interval)
    timevalues = timevalues[count:]
    print(f"[{interval[0]} : {interval[-1]}] : {count}")
    return counter(timevalues)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    times = [-1.9493, -1.9433, -1.911, -1.8977, -1.8671]
    print(counter(times))
```

Adapt it as you wish, for example you might want to return a dictionary rather that a string.

You could still get around this without using the `python-intervals` library here but i have introduced it here because it will be very likely that you would need other complex operations along the way on your code.